# Get list of Offline/Saved Videos through YouTube API

Tags: rest, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need some help to get list of videos which is downloaded(or taken offline) by a user.

Does YouTube Rest API provide us any API to get list of saved video?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you will not be able to list offline videos from other users, even your own offline videos. [This stack exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145968/get-the-list-of-downloaded-youtube-offline-videos-title-from-another-device) post discussed the reason.

> Those "offline" videos can only be played using official YouTube App,
>   and those videos simply can not be played using any other Video/Media
>   player application.
>
> YouTube (means Google) controls the access to the offline file.
>
> The permission is controlled on their server to access those
>   downloaded files and Since they are part of specific device, you
>   cannot access/view those using Google Account, from another device.

But if you want to list videos in youtube api, you can refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list).